# Installing a homebrew/linuxbrew formula on an Android device

Tags: adb, installation, apk, command-line

How would one go about installing a simple homebrew/linuxbrew formula on an Android device via adb? Specifically, I want to install [this formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/aamath) which contains a cli tool called aamath that translates mathematical formulas into ASCII art. I would want to verify that I can run this tool inside an adb shell session. Then a second step (which I may ask in a future question on this site) would be to write my own APK that invokes this tool.